# How can I generate the result with a sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Original table:

[image]

See country column in the result.
In a word, I would like to list provinces having the most population in every country and then the provinces having second largest population in each country.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to give the data in text format rather than image as we cannot copy text for image to replicate the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[`Rextester Demo`](http://rextester.com/MRBJ30991)**</kbd>

There are 2 discrepancies in your expected output.

1. `c2p1 800` is placed before `c3p2 900` which I assume is incorrect.
2. In result, 7th row is `c2p1` but it should be `c3p1` which I belive is a typo.

Also I left the logic for generating sequence number to you, which you can easily google.

```
select t1.country,t1.province,t1.population
from tbl1 t1
inner join tbl1 t2
on t1.country=t2.country
where t1.population <= t2.population 
group by t1.country,t1.province
order by count(*),t1.population desc;
```

Output

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| country | province | population |
+---------+----------+------------+
| C1      | C1P3     |       1500 |
| C3      | C3P2     |        900 |
| C2      | C2P1     |        800 |
| C4      | C4P1     |        100 |
| C1      | C1P1     |       1000 |
| C2      | C2P2     |        500 |
| C3      | C3P1     |        100 |
| C1      | C1P2     |        500 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Explanation: Self join with `where` condition  `where t1.population <= t2.population` and `group by t1.country,t1.province` will replicate windows function `row_Number() over partition by` which is not available in MySQL.

Limitation: Assuming `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled for you, else you would need one more join to display `population` as it is not in `group by` field.

Comment: Thanks! That is true. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled

Comment: @WubinOuyang Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you, so the question could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Getting wither list is easy by using a decending sort on population and the limit clause. To get the two lists, you can use a UNION for the two lists:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            '1' as `rank_group`,
            `province`,
            `population`,
            `country`
        FROM `table` a
        GROUP BY `province`,`country`
        ORDER BY `population` DESC
        LIMIT 0,1
    )
UNION
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            '2' as `rank_group`,
            `province`,
            `population`,
            `country`
        FROM `table` a
        GROUP BY `province`,`country`
        ORDER BY `population` DESC
        LIMIT 1,1
    )
ORDER BY `rank_group`,`population` DESC;
```